# Android/Sony Smartwatch: Unable to instantiate receiver (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, sony-smartwatch

I got an ClassNotFoundException with a static broadcastreceiver. The exception is fired when installing the app via eclipse on the device. I am developing an sony smartwatch extension, so I need to use the "SmartExtensionUtils" project from the sony sdk. As long as I was working inside the code example project everything was fine. I started a new project with Maven + Android and now it is no longer working!!! No idea why?!? I reckon something with the packages went wrong....

I got the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.bla.move.smartwatch.sony.ExtensionReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bla.move.smartwatch.sony.ExtensionReceiver
```

My broadcastreceiver class is called ExtensionReceiver. The name inside the manifest file is the same ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bla.move.smartwatch.sony"
  android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.EXTENSION_PERMISSION" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="SmartWatchPreferenceActivity" android:label="@string/preference_activity_title">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".SmartWatchExtensionService" />

    <receiver android:name=".ExtensionReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
       .....
     </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    ....
```

What could be the problem? Any  suggestions??? I did alreday clean + rebuild (a couple of times)!

Comment: Side note: you are missing a dot in front of SmartWatchPreferenceActivity

Comment: Dumb question coming: the receiver class does actually exist in your project within the correct package?

Comment: Yes, it exists!!! ;-) Inside the (only) package "com.bla.move.smartwatch.sony" ...

Comment: And the class ExtensionReceiver is located in it's own file.

Comment: Very hard to tell without seeing the entire project setup..

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the `SmartExtensionAPI` and `SmartExtensionUtil` projects as dependencies, both in your project and in Maven?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the workspace (start Eclipse with the -clean flag), and make sure your project's JDK compliance settings is set to 1.6 (not 1.7)! That worked for me. I set the JDK compliance level of the whole workspace, instead of the project itself, and the error just disappeared!